# result isn't correct when use reportprogress

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have listview with items add static and have text value sequence : 1,2,3,4,5,6
when I select items so will have correspond backgroundworker thread perform

e.g : I select 3 items so have 3 backgroundworker thread perform

everything is ok until I add reportprogress of backgroundworker to dislay progressBar so result when select items is not correct

e.g : I select 3 items with value text is 2,3,5 so result show is 2,2,5

I try debugging but can't find error

somebody help me, please!!!!

```
private static int numOfTheards = 0;
BackgroundWorker[] threadArray;
List<string> lst = null;
int i ;


private void InitializeBackgoundWorkers()
{

    for (int f = 0; f < numOfTheards; f++)
    {
        threadArray[f] = new BackgroundWorker();
        threadArray[f].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        threadArray[f].RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        threadArray[f].ProgressChanged +=new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        threadArray[f].WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        threadArray[f].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }
}



private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{           
    string kq = "";
    while (i < lst.Count)
    {
        kq = lst[i];
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i * 100 / listViewEx1.Items.Count);
        ++i;
        break;
    }
    labelX1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { labelX1.Text += kq + "-"; }));    
}




private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;
    labelX1.Text = "";
    InitializeBackgoundWorkers();
    for (int a = 0; a < numOfTheards; a++)
    {
        if (threadArray[a].IsBusy)
        {
            threadArray[a].CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            progressBarX1.Value = progressBarX1.Minimum;
            threadArray[a].RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}



private void listViewEx1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelX2.Text = "";
    numOfTheards = listViewEx1.SelectedItems.Count;
    threadArray = new BackgroundWorker[numOfTheards];

    lst = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewEx1.SelectedItems)
    {
        lst.Add(item.SubItems[0].Text);
        labelX2.Text += item.SubItems[0].Text+".";
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBarX1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressBarX1.Text = "Processing......" + progressBarX1.Value.ToString() + "%";
}
```

Comment: Your question is almost unintelligible... please clarify. `I select 3 items with value text is 2,3,5 so result show is 2,2,5` so what is the *expected* result?

Comment: I select 3 items with value text is 2,3,5 so result is shown in Label is 2,2,5.sorry my english is bad.

Comment: That's not what I asked. What is the **expected result**? Why is `2,2,5` wrong? Please explain.

Comment: expected result that I want : 2,3,5. mean is that Selectitems is selected so will have correspond backgroundworker thread perform and show value text of items to label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have serious issues understanding multi-threading. For example, you're using a *global* variable `i`, which is modified by the background worker code - what tells you that there are no race conditions? (There are race conditions obviously, otherwise you wouldn't have the problems you're having.

At least mark `i` `volatile`, even better, really re-think your code design.

---

By the way it is not really amazing that the problem occurs. I'll explain why:

You used the common variable `i` to make sure that 3 background workers worked on the list, but not two of them worked on the same item. That obviously didn't work in your case, as you did not implement any proper way of making sure that only one background worker gets to work on an entry alone.

Example: Two background workers start their work. Both get the value `i == 0` to work on, as you didn't make sure that the operations "get item at index `i`" and "increment `i`" are atomic (meaning: treated as one operation with which no other thread can interfere).

What you could have done was to lock access to `i` entirely like this:

```
private volatile int i;
private object iLock = new object();

...

while (i < lst.Count)
{
    int previousI;

    lock (iLock)
    {
        previousI = i;
        kq = lst[i];
        ++i;
    }

    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(previousI * 100 / listViewEx1.Items.Count);

    ...
}
```

What does that do? It creates a locked section - only one thread can enter it at the same time. It then remembers the current value of `i` *locally* for the current thread, gets the list entry and increments `i`. All this is done so that only *one thread at a time* can access `i`.

In the further course of action, it uses `previousI`, because `i` could already be modified by another thread outside the locked block.

**Why this code sucks**
You have too many places where `i` is accessed and can not properly lock them all.

**What I'd do**
Instead of playing with `i`, I'd "partition" the data every background worker works on. For example, I'd create a list of arrays. Every entry in the list contains an array of `lst` items for every background worker. Then I'd have every background worker work autonomically on its own list.

---

**How to partition your data**

Without having tried anything, I'd do the following:

The following code is executed when you press a button:

```
private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;
    labelX1.Text = "";
    InitializeBackgoundWorkers();
    for (int a = 0; a < numOfTheards; a++)
    {
        if (threadArray[a].IsBusy)
        {
            threadArray[a].CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            progressBarX1.Value = progressBarX1.Minimum;
            threadArray[a].RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is already wrong. You call `InitializeBackgroundWorkers` which actually initializes new background workers in an array, which is newly created in `listViewEx1_SelectedIndexChanged`. No use in cancelling any workers in this code, as they *can't* be running, as you only created them. If you want to cancel running workers before creating new ones, you need to cancel them before creating a new worker array in `listViewEx1_SelectedIndexChanged`. But that's only a side note.

Having initialized the workers, generate the data to process **for each worker**. I understand that you want each worker to process the `SubItem[0]` of one item selected within a list view. That list of items to be processed is already generated in `listViewEx1_SelectedIndexChanged`: `lst`. So because now there's one background worker for each item in `lst`, this comes down to:

```
private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;
    labelX1.Text = "";
    InitializeBackgoundWorkers();

    progressBarX1.Value = progressBarX1.Minimum;
    for (int a = 0; a < numOfTheards; a++)
    {
        string itemData = lst[a];
        threadArray[a].RunWorkerAsync(itemData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know my code is issue but I not still can find it. can you help me ??

Comment: Remove the variable `i` entirely. Remove the line `i = 0` from the button's event handler. Within the background worker's work method, replace the `while` loop by a `for` loop on a local variable like `for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)`.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.I will fix now !!

Comment: Instead of playing with 'lock', another way better than 'lock'.Because i read some disadvantages when use 'lock':  Priority Inversion High priority threads/processes cannot proceed, if a low priority thread/process is holding the common lock.

Comment: Well, the miracles of multi threading. You need to lock your resources, not matter what. If you don't, you get in trouble - and you are already, as you can see. Of course, any thread can't process if any other thread holds a resource. That's just how it goes.

Comment: One way of freeing yourself from the need to lock resources is to make sure thread don't use common resources at all. That would be the case in the *What I'd do* section above.

Comment: I quit golbal variable and use follow your _What I'll do_ section.I read and understand it but can't transfer my ideal to code.how to ensure only 1 backgroundwoker do only 1 items is selected?Can't input foreach(Listviewitem i in ListView1.SelectedItems) so every BakgroundWorker do all items is selected ???

Comment: thank you, man !!It's simple so I think so far.I fixed it and now apply this code enter my project because this is sample project that I have been to use backgroundworker.

Comment: you have ID facebook or yahoo og skype or gmail so maybe I need your help for more that ??

Comment: You can always ask new specific questions here on SO.

Comment: so I have 3 bronze badges so I can not ask at here

Comment: Huh? You asked the question. If you have another, ask another question. That has nothing to do with the number of badges you have...?

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account".when I push ask question so show this waring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467732/how-to-wait-and-get-text-from-another-form-in-multiple-backgroundworker Please, help me !!!